# Why does dynamically allocated array does not update with the new data coming?

Tags: c, sockets, pointers

I am trying to receive a message from the socket server which sends a large file of around 7MB. Thus in the following code, I try to concatenate all data into one array `s` from `buffer`. But as I try the following, I see that the length of `s` does not change at all, although the total bytes received continue to increase.

```
char buffer[300];
char* s = calloc(1, sizeof(char));
size_t n = 1;
while ((b_recv = recv(socket_fd,
                              buffer,
                              sizeof(buffer), 0)) > 0) {


   char *temp = realloc(s, b_recv + n);
   s = temp;
   memcpy(s + n -1, buffer, b_recv);
   n += b_recv;
   s[n-1] = '\0';
   printf("%s -- %zu",s, strlen(s));

}

free(s);
```

Is this not the correct way to update receive data of varying sizes? Also when I try to print `s`, it gives some random question mark characters. What is the mistake that I am making?

Comment: Use a debugger to inspect `buffer`. Are you maybe receiving null bytes?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `buffer` has binary data.

Comment: Well there you have it, then.  `strlen()` is not suitable for measuring binary data, because it interprets the first character with value 0 as a string terminator.  Adding more data past that will not alter `strlen()`'s interpretation of the length. Nor does it make much sense to print such data for reading as text when it is *not*, in fact, text.

Comment: You can't print binary data using `printf` and cannot measure binary data dimension using `strlen`. `printf` and `strlen` act on 0 terminated vectors of chars. C doesn't manage strings, but only 0-terminated vectors of chars.

Comment: `s[n-1] = '\0';` You are overwiting the final character here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does dynamically allocated array does not update with the new data coming?

You have not presented any reason to believe that the behavior is as the question characterizes it.  You are receiving binary data and storing it in memory, which is fine, but you cannot expect sensible results from treating such data as if it were a C string.  Not even when you replace the last byte with a string terminator.

Binary data can and generally does contain bytes with value 0.  C strings use such bytes as terminators marking the end of the string data, so, for example, `strlen` will measure only the number of bytes before the first zero byte, regardless of how many additional bytes have been stored after it.  Moreover, even if you do not receive any zero bytes at all, your particular code *inserts* them, clobbering some of the real bytes received.

You may attempt to print such data to the console as if it were text, but if in fact it does not consist of text encoded according to the runtime character encoding then there is no reason to expect the resulting display to convey useful information.  Instead, examine it in memory via a debugger, or write the raw bytes to a file and examine the result with a hex editor, or write them (still raw) through a filter that converts to hexadecimal or some other text representation, or similar.  And you have as many bytes to examine as you have copied to the allocated space.  You're keeping track of that already, so you don't need `strlen()` to tell you how many that is.

Comment: How do I take care of case where the server sends me a text file (which is just plain strings).  The server could send an image file (binary) or a text file. Wouldn't I need to add `\0` if the text file is being received?

Comment: @Amanda you need to know the format of the file before you print it out. If it is text, print it as text. If it is binary, print it as hex instead. Either way, you really shouldn't be dealing with `\0` at all. Use the actual byte length of the data instead. Even when you print out text, you can specify the length so you don't need to terminate the text with `\0`